Show that $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)g(x-t)dt$ is 2 times differentiable and that $f''+f=g$
Given g(x) a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, show that $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)g(x-t)dt$ is 2 times differentiable and that $f''+f=g$. This problem reminds me another one where $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)(x-t)dt$$
and so
$$f'(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)xdt-\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)tdt\right)'= \int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)dt+x\sin(x)-\sin(x)x=-\cos(x)+1$$
But here, we do not have a way to split the $g(x-t)$.

I have not checked the function myself, but should the Leibniz integral rule not work?

I tried Leibniz integral rule, but couldn't get farther from :
By Leibniz rule of differentiating under integral sign we get:
$f^{'}(x) = \sin (x) g(0) + \int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)g^{'}(x-t)$
$f^{''}(x) = \cos(x)g(0)+ \sin(x)g^{'}(0)+ \int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)g^{''}(x-t)$
$f^{''} + f = \cos(x)g(0) +\sin(x)g^{'}(0)+ \int_{0}^{x}\sin (t)g^{''}(x-t)+\sin (t)g(x-t)$

Here is a hint: Let $y=x-t$.
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\int_{0}^{x} \sin(x-y)g(y)dy=\int_{0}^{x} \left(\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)\right)g(y)dy\\&=\sin(x)\int_{0}^{x} \cos(y)g(y)dy-\cos(x) \int_{0}^{x} \sin(y)g(y)dy \end{align}$$
Then you can differentiate it:
$$\begin{align} \frac{df}{dx}&=\cos(x)\int_{0}^{x} \cos(y)g(y)dy+\sin(x)\cos(x)g(x)+\sin(x)\int_{0}^{x} \sin(y)g(y)dy-\cos(x)\sin(x)g(x)\\& \end{align}$$
Then differentiate it again: $$ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\left(\cos(x)\int_{0}^{x} \cos(y)g(y)dy+\sin(x)\int_{0}^{x} \sin(y)g(y)dy\right)'$$ You can try it now.

Also, notice that your computation for f'(x) was wrong and I have corrected that mistake.

please use \sin and \cos for better formatting ($\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ in place of $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$)

@Didier Thank you for your advise.

@Morten Nicely seen, by the way, to computate all those integrals shouldn't the problem guarantee the differentiability of g?

@MiguelCG If g is differentiable, it's ok. If g is continuous, I think it still works: f is integrable on [0,x] and by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt$ is differentiable and the product of two integrable functions is still integrable.
